Can you hack bots diagonally?
According to this Steam discussion page, you can use multitools in Jupiter Hell to hack and take over mechanical enemies. However, if your technician doesn't have the 'Remote Hack' trait, then you have to move into the bots to hack them. Does that mean you can't hack a bot that is diagonally next to you (since you can't move diagonally in a single turn)?

Wait until Kornel is here again :)

@DaemonsMercy Ha ha! Yeah, I could probably just go on to their Discord and ask him :-)

@DaemonsMercy you rang?

@KornelKisielewicz Yes, there’s another Jupiter Hell question on line 3 for you.

You can't! The same as you can't close doors diagonally (which are actually terminals).

Ok, thanks for your answer! I have recently been trying out the hacking mechanics - it seems that Remote Hacking could be used to do it (which looks like a v useful trait)
